# In Atlassian Bamboo, is there any way to export build results to Excel sheet or at least as CSV?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, bitbucket-server

In Atlassian Bamboo, is there any way to export the daily E2E test runs from bamboo to excel sheet, so that I can monitor my project status.

I'm also looking for any other better solution if the above is not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Pulling bamboo RSS feed into excel is one option.

1- [Bamboo RSS feeds](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/subscribing-to-rss-feeds-289276970.html)

2- [Show RSS Feeds in Excel](https://www.contextures.com/excelrssfeeds.html)